# JToolbar: JToggleButton Alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar, jtogglebutton

I am attempting to align JToggleButtons in a JToolBar. I want the buttons to be aligned vertically and to the left. My code is as follows:

```
JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
toolbar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
toolbar.setAlignmentX(FlowLayout.LEFT);
toolbar.add(new JToggleButton("Test"));
toolbar.add(new JToggleButton("Test2"));
toolbar.add(new JToggleButton("Test3"));
toolbar.add(new JToggleButton("Test with a long name"));
```

This is what the result looks like.
[image: my JToolBar]

Also, when docked to the left, it looks like this. Ideally, I want the buttons to stack on each other vertically (and still remain aligned to the left). Any tips?

[image: JToolBar docked to the left]

The ideal results should look like this:
[image: Ideal results - left aligned buttons, and stacked when the toolbar is docked to the left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the buttons to align to the left

This is the default behaviour for a JToolBar. There is no need to play with the layout manager.

> I want the buttons to stack on each other vertically

Again, this is the default behaviour when used with the default layout manager.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response, but that still doesn't answer my question (perhaps I worded it weird?). I want to move the buttons to look like this (as in, the buttons align to the left of the toolbar and stack vertically when docked to the left): http://puu.sh/seMS7/4e3347c203.png

Comment: @JoeBalin, Did you download the demo code from the tutorial and test it?

Comment: I went back and copy-pasted the example code. Basically, I had initialized the ButtonGroup earlier in the program, so I only had to loop through the button group and add each button to the toolbar. However, by defining a new ButtonGroup and then adding the buttons back to, it magically fixed it, and they align properly. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

A FlowLayout can only lay out components in horizontal rows, wrapping around like the way text "flows" on a page.

You could change to a vertical BoxLayout: `toolbar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toolbar, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));` or get the same effect (since JToolBar uses a BoxLayout by default) by calling the constructor `new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL)`

To left align, though, I believe you will need to call `setAlignmentX(FlowLayout.LEFT)` for ***each*** Component you add, not the toolbar itself or its layout.  See, for example, [the BoxLayout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features).